# Touchpad disabled and cursor invisible with touchscreen laptop on 13.10

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, touchscreen, cursor

I have an ASUS S400C running Ubuntu 13.10. After shutting down overnight and restarting this morning, I noticed there was no visible mouse cursor and trackpad events were not firing - no left or right click, no two-finger scrolling. The touchscreen is still working fine, however the pointer sprite isn't displayed. If I log out, the touchpad mouse works fine and is visible on the log in screen. If I move the cursor around with the touchpad while it is logging in, it freezes at a point between the log in screen and my account opening, while the screen is still black. Using the touchscreen after that point causes the cursor to become invisible again.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

has no effect.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

renders the cursor visible, but the touchpad is still disabled. The cursor remains visible for touchscreen events.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active true
```

returns the situation to as originally described.

In short: help!

EDIT 1: Output of `synclient -l`:

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 129
    RightEdge               = 3120
    TopEdge                 = 120
    BottomEdge              = 2103
    FingerLow               = 1
    FingerHigh              = 1
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 173
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 78
    HorizScrollDelta        = 78
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.050813
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 19
    VertHysteresis          = 19
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1624
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 1822
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: please provide output of > synclient -l

Comment: sgx1 : I've updated the question with that at "EDIT 1"

Comment: obviously, your touchpad is not enabled. Option "TouchpadOff" 0      Touchpad is enabled
              1   Touchpad is switched off
              2   Only tapping and scrolling is switched off

Comment: in your case TouchpadOff=2, so tapping and scrolling is switched off.

Comment: go to system settings->mouse&touchpad and test with the touchpad options.

Comment: sgx1 : Touchpad was set to OFF, just as you said! Such an obvious thing to check, but didn't check because I hadn't touched it recently. Thanks for your help, though I wish you'd have posted your comment as an answer so I could award you the points you deserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously, your touchpad is not enabled. see > man synaptics :

> Option "TouchpadOff"
>    0 Touchpad is enabled
>    1 Touchpad is switched off
>    2 Only tapping and scrolling is switched off

in your case TouchpadOff=2, so tapping and scrolling is switched off.

go to system settings->mouse&touchpad and enable touchpad.

NOTE: **synclient** is is always your friend when debugging touchpad. all its options are
      documented by '**man synaptics**'. you can change touchpad options directly by **synclient**, but the settings can not persist after the user session. this is when gnome-settings-daemon comes into play. gnome-settings-daemon re-applies the system settings every time a new user session starts.