# Ubuntu 14.04 mouse touchpad isn't responding

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, elantech

My computer shut down when the battery was depleted and before I could plug it in and since restarting it, the touchpad doesn't respond if I move my finger on it. The buttons do.

xinput is able to recognize the device and the button clicks but nothing happens when I move my finger. The pointer remains static and the terminal doesn't show any changes in output.

```
$ xinput --test 12
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   1 
button press   3 
button release 3 
button press   3 
button release 3 

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

id=12 is my touchpad while the wireless device must be my wireless mouse. I double checked the mouse settings and all looks fine. How did I fix this error with my touchpad?

EDIT: 
This disables the device but setting the property to 1 again doesn't reset the touchpad.

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Comment: It seems that you are thorough, but just to exclude another option: Is there a Fn button or so on the keyboard that enables and disables the mouse pad?

Comment: what about suspending the computer - `function+insert` does the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off and on your touchpad from the settings. 
Try this command as well: gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true

EDIT: According to sgx1's answer ([Touchpad disabled and cursor invisible with touchscreen laptop on 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397034/touchpad-disabled-and-cursor-invisible-with-touchscreen-laptop-on-13-10))  , there are three options:
Option "TouchpadOff"
    0 Touchpad is enabled
    1 Touchpad is switched off
    2 Only tapping and scrolling is switched off

Using xinput:
The following script does not need SHMConfig to be enabled - it works on out-of-the-box Ubuntu. It does not need any of the steps above to be performed. Works without superuser rights.

export `xinput list | grep -i touchpad | awk '{ print $6 }'`
TOUCH_ENABLED=`xinput list-props $id | grep Device\ Enabled | awk '{ print $4 }'`
if [ $TOUCH_ENABLED = 0 ]; then
        xinput set-prop $id "Device Enabled" 1
elif [ $TOUCH_ENABLED = 1 ]; then
        xinput set-prop $id "Device Enabled" 0
else
        echo "Could not get touchpad status from xinput"
        exit 1
fi
exit 0

Xinput command to change touchpad value: xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1

Synclient command: synclient touchpadoff=0 -- this rarely works

If you disabled the touchpad using another operating system, the only solution is turning the touchpad back on from the second operating system.

Another solution is adding a line to this file:
cd /usr/local/bin

gksudo gedit tpoff (Add this to the file: synclient touchpadoff=0)

My last suggestion is that you check the xorg configutation file by issuing the following command: gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Look for the following section of code:

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier      "Synaptics Touchpad"
        Driver          "synaptics"
        Option          "SendCoreEvents"        "true"
        Option          "Device"                "/dev/psaux"
        Option          "Protocol"              "auto-dev"
        Option          "HorizScrollDelta"      "0"
EndSection

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work. And the touchpad is already enabled in the settings, so turning it off and back on again did not work. I have restarted the computer multiple times too and don't really know what's wrong with this. Is there a xinput command that I can use to change the touchpad values?